# Plugin to Test End-User Browser Compatiblity (ACID scoring perhaps)

Tags: jquery, html, testing

We have many users all over the country with varying levels of technical experience (mostly none). On top of this, the warehouse environment often contains computers that are decades old running browsers that are impossibly out of date.

Among other reasons, we have a desire to essentially run a test the first time the site sees a computer to determine if the browser can support our site, and notify the user and prevent the site's use if it does not (and when possible notify us so we can proactively reach out to the customer and get them compliant, or send them a new computer to use, depending).

Rather than re-invent the wheel, I was hoping something like this already existed as open source software. Preferably as a jQuery plugin.

I know jQuery supports/recommends feature detection, but rather than implement this, it would be cool to run a plugin/script/whatever the returns a probability or boolean value that the browser will work and is compliant with modern standards.

I can't find anything like this, and am beginning to wonder if it's possible, or if I'm just not searching for the right stuff.

Comment: [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) is the *right* way to solve this problem. Yes, it means more work for you, but that's what developers are paid for.